# Tensorflow class balancing for training multi-class classification network

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, image-segmentation, conv-neural-network

I am training a classification neural network for multiple classes. I have very imbalanced classes (80:10:5:5 ratio approximately). I want to use some kind of weight balancing in the loss function to prevent the neural network from overly predicting for the majority class. Does anybody know how to do the class balancing in Tensorflow?

P.S. I cannot solve this by over-sampling the minority classes because I am training a convolutional-deconvolutional neural network that does medical image segmentation. Each pixels is assigned to a distinct class in this task. I cannot over sample pixels in this task.

Thanks a lot!:D

Than

Comment: So, you have the solution which is to add class specific weights to the loss function. What part of that are you stuck on?

Comment: hi, what I did is to multiply the final logits layer with the class weight like:     weighted_logits=tf.mul(logits,class_weights). It does not seem to work very well as some minority class is still under-predicted. so I want to ask if there is other better ways of doing this.

Comment: I know that you can add instances/classes weight in Keras (framework above TensorFlow and Theano).

Comment: @WangDuo what you tried is the right thing to do. I'm not sure why it is still under-predicted.

Comment: @FiReTiTi Thanks for the info

Comment: @Aaron I have tried Median Frequency Balancing and it works better now(though not perfect). I think the problem was I used a less accurate balancing method.